# Sum of the rows of a particular column of a table using C# sql

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, asp.net, sum

There is a field 'price' in a table  'transfer'. I need sum total of the price column and show it to a label, using Asp.Net C#. I have tried several coding, but failed.Here is the code, it shows error in the 4th line

```
SQLConnection dbConn = new SQLConnection("server=serverName,database=laptop");
dbConn.Open();
SqlCommand query = new SqlCommand("Select Sum(price) FROM transfer");
query.Connection = dbConn;
int sum = (Int32)query.ExecuteScalar();
lbl2.Text = sum.ToString();
```

Anyone please suggest me an alternate code, or what to change in the present one to make it run.
Thanx.

Comment: What error do you get?

Comment: Enclose all of code to `try -- catch`, hold the exception in variable, and paste `exception` message here.

Comment: To few elements to reply. Just one think, SQLConnection and SqlCommand are both IDisposable, therefore you should declare them within "using" block or dispose them once used.

Answer (score 1):

If the connection string is OK (this could be one issue) and the query is correct (existing table and column) then I suspect that (since the name of the column is Price) you should cast to to Decimal:

```
Decimal sum = (Decimal)query.ExecuteScalar();
```

Works from here.

Answer (score 0):

```
 con.Open();
 string syntax = "SELECT Sum(price) FROM transfer";
 cmd = new SqlCommand(syntax, con);
 dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
 dr.Read();
 lbl2.Text = dr[0].ToString();
 con.Close();
```